# Python AI Login Program error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

So im currently making an responsive AI my issue:

```
player_name = input()

if player_name('Waller'):
    print("Login Valid! Welcome ODST Waller")
```

: so this is the code that is giving me the issue, the error message that I receive is:

if player_name('Waller'):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

:Every time I run my program this message pops up and i'm not entirely sure what to do

Answer (score 3):

`input()` method returns a string, so you can just compare them:

```
player_name = input()

if player_name == 'Waller':
   print("Login Valid! Welcome ODST Waller")
```